# Passing GET params to controller with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, capybara

What is the proper way to test token authentication with Capybara? Here is what I have:

```
describe ApplicationController do
  let!(:user) { create :user, authentication_token: 1 }

  specify "token should work now" do
    visit "/?auth_token=#{user.authentication_token}"
    # get :index
    response.should_not redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
  end

  specify "token shouldn't work in the future" do
    Timecop.travel(2.weeks)
    visit "/?auth_token=#{user.authentication_token}"
    # get :index
    response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_url)
    Timecop.return
  end
end
```

Tests fail if I don't have the `get :index` line. But if I comment out that line, the test is saved, but that should not be the right way since I have `visit` above it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: response comes from get and visit returns a page if I remember correctly. I bet when you have `get :index` commented out its confused what response is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `visit` doesn't pass variables to controller. Changing it to `get :index, auth_token: user.authentication_token` fixed the issue.